# Roaming functionality in windows 7

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, active-directory, group-policy

I am creating a client application. This application just give users some choices and saves their choices inside 'C:\Users\Userid\AppData\Roaming\Custom1\Config1' as text Files.

I assumed that if the user logs in from other machine in the same domain their Roaming folder will move with them.

This does not seem to happen.

Does it need any setting change in Active directory Group policy or anything. I am a C# developer but do not have much idea about networking and windows server or Active directory settings etc.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as to where to look for a solution for this.

Comment: Are you using the `Environment.GetFolderPath` to retrieve the path to the roaming application data folder?

Answer (score 0):

Roaming profiles do not include AppData by default.  There is a group policy Folder Redirection area where you can redirect AppData, although that creates a lot of unnecessary network traffic in addition to roaming profiles.  May be better off saving to a folder inside the roaming profile itself, and setting your program to do some sort of purge of that folder after X days so it doesn't bog down the log on process.  Or have the program save to their networked home directory.